# In reactusestate setcart function is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

const addToCart = (item) => {
  // cart.push(item);
  setCart(...cart, item);
  console.log(cart);
};
```

when I try to update cart with cart.push() , it is updating cart
but when i try to update cart with setCart then its showing this error

```
=> TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

Comment: `setCart([...cart, item])`. [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) documentation will help you

Comment: Additionally, you can't console.log the new state of cart after setCart. Because react setState is async. To log the new state, use useEffect hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this without bugs would be to use a function inside `setCart` that takes the previous state and updates it.
It would look like this:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

const addToCart = (item) => {
    setCart(prevState => {
      return [...prevState, item];
    });
}
```

An alternative shorter syntax (does the same thing) using would be:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

const addToCart = item => setCart(prevState => ([...prevState, item]));
```

Comment: The first solution is mutating `prevState` object

Comment: That's great, please consider upvoting the answer as well.